# Using JavaScript onclick function to change innerHTML to form field

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to use the JavaScript onclick() function to change a piece of HTML to a Django Model Form field when clicked?

Using the code below, I would expect that when the `{{ tasks.owner }}` is clicked, the html with id "task_owner" would change to  `{{ task_update_form.owner }}`.

My Django template is below:

```
<script>

function OwnerUpdate() {
  document.getElementById("task_owner").innerHTML =  "{{ task_update_form.owner }}";
}

</script>

<p id = "task_owner", onclick = "OwnerUpdate()"> {{ tasks.owner }} </p>
```

If I use the below code - substituting `{{ task_update_form.owner }}` with `"Test"` it works perfectly.

```
<script>

function OwnerUpdate() {
  document.getElementById("task_owner").innerHTML =  "Test";
}

</script>

<p id = "task_owner", onclick = "OwnerUpdate()"> {{ tasks.owner }} </p>
```

I have also tested it using non-form context from my views.py and it works.

`{{ task_update_form.owner }}` works fine when inserted into the Django template normally.

My experience with JavaScript is limited and I would be grateful for any help.

Client side code for the `OwnerUpdate` function is below:

```
<select name="owner" class="specific_task_header" required="" id="id_owner">
  <option value="">---------</option>

  <option value="1" selected="">Peter</option>

</select>
```

Function code is per below:

```
function OwnerUpdate() {
  document.getElementById("task_owner").innerHTML =  "<select name="owner" class="specific_task_header" required id="id_owner">
  <option value="">---------</option>

  <option value="1" selected>Peter</option>

</select>";
}
```

Leading to error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Changing to `'{{ task_update_form.owner }}'`

```
function OwnerUpdate() {
  document.getElementById("task_owner").innerHTML =  '{{ task_update_form.owner }}';
}
```

produces the following code:

```
function OwnerUpdate() {
  document.getElementById("task_owner").innerHTML =  '<select name="owner" class="specific_task_header" required id="id_owner">
  <option value="">---------</option>

  <option value="1" selected>tom</option>

</select>';
}
```

Comment: The JavaScript code has no knowledge of the server-side Django code which produced it.  What is the client-side code that this produces?

Comment: Hi David, `task_update_form.owner` produces a drop down list to choose from. If I use `{{ obj }}`, which is taken from `'obj' : IndividualTask.objects.get(id=id),` in my views.py context, it does work. Is it not possible to use JavaScript here? Could the desired outcome be reached with CSS?

Comment: It is likely possible to use JavaScript here.  But you're going to need to understand that JavaScript only operates on the *client-side* code, not the *server-side* code.  To write your JavaScript code you need to have an understanding of what the server-side code is actually producing.  Open your browser's debugging tools to see what is actually written in that `OwnerUpdate` function.  What is the actual resulting client-side code?  In your browser's debugging tools, are there any errors on the console?  Either before or after invoking the click event?

Comment: Thanks David, I've added the code produced by `task_update_form.owner`. I have also added how the function `OwnerUpdate` is translated in the Django Template causing the `Unexpected Identifier` error. I assume this is because I am looking to change the innerHTML and `OwnerUpdate` cover more than that?There is a further error in the console `Uncaught ReferenceError: OwnerUpdate is not defined at HTMLParagraphElement.onclick`

Comment: The JavaScript code produced is full of syntax errors, which is why it isn't working as expected.  You have double-quote characters inside of a double-quote string.  You can try making it a single-quote string instead.  Of course, if there's ever a single-quote character then you would run into the same problem.  Perhaps Django has a way to escape string values like this to be used in JavaScript?

Comment: I didn't think that HTML changed based on single vs double quotes. Are you able to explain how the JavaScript code should look please?

Comment: At the moment it has nothing to do with HTML.  The JavaScript code has syntax errors, because double-quoted strings can't contain un-escaped double-quotes.  (No language can do that, because there's no way to consistently parse/tokenize it.)  For this specific example, you can try using a single-quoted string instead: `document.getElementById("task_owner").innerHTML =  '{{ task_update_form.owner }}';`  In JavaScript there's *almost* no difference between the two.  The main difference here would be that a one type of string can contain the other type of quotes.

Comment: Thanks David - I have made the change you suggested and posted the code above. Unfortunately received the following error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

Comment: Hmm... Looks like single-quoted strings can't contain carriage returns either.  Using back-ticks should though.  That would technically make the string a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), but it's still a string.  Though I suspect there's a more Django-appropriate way to accomplish what you're doing.  And unfortunately I have no Django experience, I can only help with the JavaScript/HTML parts.

Comment: Thanks for your time David - back ticks did work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was coming for enclosing ``` {{ task_update_form.owner }}`` in "" and can be solved using backticks to create a template literal (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Working function is below:

```
function OwnerUpdate() {
  document.getElementById("task_owner").innerHTML =  `{{ task_update_form.owner }}`;
}
```